# Latest xparse/amsmath update doesn't work well in align

Tags: align, amsmath, optional-arguments, xparse

The following minimal example doesn't compile when the optional argument to `\macro` is used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\macro}{o}{A\IfValueT{#1}{(#1)}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  abc \macro \\
  def \macro[A]% Error
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I'm using the following file list:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  xparse.sty    2016/03/26 v6466 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2016/03/26 v6466 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2016/03/26 v6466 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2016/03/26 v6465 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
 amsmath.sty    2016/03/03 v2.15a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
 ***********
```

I'm not sure whether the problem may lie, as both [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) and [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) was recently updated.

Comment: Joseph has screwed up the L3 distribution.

Comment: More precisely, a change in the internals of `expl3` has made `xparse` buggy in that respect; today's update of `l3packages` makes it completely unusable. `:(`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most recent update to `l3kernel` made the code for optional arguments in a command defined by `\NewDocumentCommand` not working in all circumstances (this happens especially with `align`).

The update to `l3packages` (among which there is `xparse`) issued on 2016/03/28 fixes the problem.

Unfortunately, it also makes `xparse` unusable, because it requires a non existent version of `l3kernel` (it wants 2016/03/28, but 2016/03/26 is available as a release date for `l3kernel`).

I fixed by hand the date and your example works. I'm pretty sure this is just a temporary problem and that the goof will be fixed as soon as possible.

### Update, April 1, 2016

After today's update with `tlmgr`, the issue has been solved for TeX Live and your example compiles without errors.

I believe that also an updated MiKTeX will work.

```
> tlmgr info l3kernel l3packages
package:     l3kernel
category:    Package
shortdesc:   LaTeX3 programming conventions
longdesc:    [...]
installed:   Yes
revision:    40184
sizes:       src: 2329k, doc: 7473k, run: 877k
relocatable: No
cat-version: SVN 6468
cat-date:    2016-03-30 18:26:01 +0200
cat-license: lppl1.3
cat-topics:  format latex3 pre-release
cat-related: l3packages l3experimental
collection:  collection-latexrecommended

package:     l3packages
category:    Package
shortdesc:   High-level LaTeX3 concepts
longdesc:    [...]
installed:   Yes
revision:    40176
sizes:       src: 301k, doc: 1673k, run: 141k
relocatable: No
cat-version: SVN 6468
cat-date:    2016-03-29 00:16:53 +0200
cat-license: lppl1.3
cat-topics:  macro-supp latex3 pre-release
cat-related: l3kernel l3experimental
collection:  collection-latexrecommended
```