# Package xparse continues to throw "Support package l3kernel too old"

Tags: miktex, latex3

I tried to compile a (flawlessly working) LaTeX document on a different computer, and suddenly was faced with the above error message printed by the xparse package (after that, many errors follow).

I'm working on both computers with miktex 2.9 (and Texnic-Center) on Windows 7 (64 bit).

I tried EVERYTHING I found on stackexchange or anywhere else on the web, including:

- Updating all packages
- Removing the l3 packages and reinstalling them
- Doing the above for both the current user and in admin mode
- Removing the complete miktex distribution and re-installing it

  - for only the current user
  - for "anyone who uses this computer"
  - with all packages
  - only the basic packages
- Downloading the newest l3 packages manually from CTAN and copying them into the miktex folder
- Refreshing the FNDB and updating formats afterwards

Nothing worked. Right now, I'm just out of ideas. ANY suggestions??

EDIT: After performing UlrikeFischer's suggestion, I get different errors. After a long compilation process, this is the log file I get:

[Log File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78851488/Lehrbuch.log)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301707/latest-xparse-amsmath-update-doesnt-work-well-in-align

Comment: Okay, this is an EXTREMELY recent post I missed :-) But I actually tried even that before, and it didn't work...

Comment: The problem will be sorted out probably in a few hours, Christian Schenk already anounced the update. In the meantime get the l3kernel.tds.zip from CTAN (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel, SVN 6468 (!!)), unpack it outside miktex, and add the root folder with miktex settings (user, not admin) as a new root.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Is there a way to know when the fixed update will be available? Because your suggestion does seem to work, but I have still some strange errors, and I'm not sure if they're related to the bug or not...

Comment: I have no idea when Christian will have time to upload and long it will take to get to your repository. But probably it is not related to your unknown problems. But as you are neither showing a minimal example, nor the error message nor the log-file ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What else should it be about when it worked before, but doesn't now, with nothing changed but updated packages? (Assuming no other packages are buggy, too.) It's a pretty big project, and when I try to extract an MWE (or rather M NOT WE) I always end up with not getting errors at all.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The error messages I get are of the type:

l.170 \end{Definition}
                      
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...\expandafter \c@lor@to@ps #1#2\@@ 
                                                  \else \expandafter \expand...

Comment: As I already wrote: One need a minimal example. I have no idea which package defines commands starting with \XC, and I will not waste my time to search for it.

Comment: Yeah, I never asked you to, you know. YOU asked me for the error message which I politely provided.

Comment: I asked your for a minimal example *and* the error message *and* the log-file. I do find it quite impolite to provide only one the three things and to ignore the other requests. Beside this you shouldn't add such informations in comments where they are quite unreadable. Edit your original question.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry - you just tried to help. But as I said, I'm not able to create a MWE. I'll edit my question and upload the log file.

Comment: You are loading pstricks but compile with pdflatex. This can't work (and never did). The other error message (from xcolor) is a follow-up error.

Comment: You are right, the package bclogo uses pstricks!! Removing it solved the problem. Thanks a lot! But anyway, I SWEAR that it worked like this before - I didn't change anything, just copied the current version to a new computer! (I know it's impossible...)

Comment: @lukas.coenig I recall dimly reading  months  ago a thread (I think on usenet f.c.t.tex) about update of  `bclogo` causing errors. Perhaps your new computer had a more up-to-date install ?

Comment: @jfbu Yeah, that would make sense. bclogo can run in pstricks mode or in tikz mode, the latter works with pdflatex. Maybe the selection of the standard mode has been changed (I have not explicitly selected tikz). I found out that it works when I put `\usepackage{bclogo}` after an `mdframed` import which includes the option `framemethod=TikZ`.

Comment: In the documentation of bclogo it says:  La syntaxe `\usepackage{bclogo}` est équivalente à `\usepackage[pstricks]{bclogo}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also encountered this problem after updating my MiKTeX installation today. A different question thread (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301738) provided a quick temporary work-around. For minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Testing:\[1,2,3\]
\end{document}
```

Changing lines 53 and 54 in `MikTeX installation directory/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty` to

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}[2016/03/26]
\@ifpackagelater{expl3}{2016/03/26}
```

Allows `xelatex` to compile the provided example.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, with plain pdflatex this did not work for me, and I can't use xelatex.

Comment: @lukas.coenig the fix is unrelated to xelatex/pdflatex and will work for either, perhaps you are getting the same error with a different package (eg xfrac) the same issue applies to all of them.  But anyway a fix is already on ctan and will be in texlive/miktex as soon as possible.

Comment: Okay, great, I'll wait for it then! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in TeX Live Utility find the update for l3kernel and install it.
In Unix/Mac systems try:
{tlmgr update l3kernel}